# Hid or show parameter based on selected parameter/filter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have two datasets which shows to drop downs for parameter selection.

one is called ResoursesFilter

```
select distinct(F17) AS [Filter] from Report_Resources where F17 <> ''
```

The other one is PlantFilter

`select distinct(F11) AS [Category] from Report_Resources where F11 <> ''`

Resourses filter returns

[image]

I only want Plant Filter to be visible / enable if Plant is selected in the Resourses Filter.

Plant Filter is only applicable if Plant is selected

If Plant is not selected on the Resources Filter I do not want to be able to select anything in the Plant Filter (Possibly disabled or hidden)

[image]

Not sure if it is possible to hide the Recourses Filter in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically hide parameters in SSRS but what you could do is show something like 'Not Applicable' as the only parameter value available.

```
IF @ResoursesFilter= 'Plant'
    BEGIN
        select distinct(F11) AS [Category] from Report_Resources where F11 <> ''
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Not Applicable' AS [Category]
    END
```

You might have to handle ignoring this value in the main dataset but that should be simple enough.

Comment: Thanks, ended up taking this route and only showing N/A if not plant